# How do you remove nested keys dynamically from Json using recursion?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I currently have a recursive function that removes ALL keys that match a pattern. Here is the background:

Example Json

```
{
    "results": [{
        "name": "john doe",
        "age": "100",
        "owned_cars": [{
            "make": "ford",
            "color": "white"
        }, {
            "make": "bmw",
            "color": "red"
        }],
        "wished_cars": [{
            "make": "honda"
        }, {
            "make": "toyota",
            "style": "sleek"
        }, {
            "style": "fat"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here's the function:

```
def remove_all_keys_matching_value(d, keys_to_remove):
    if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
        return d
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return [remove_all_keys_matching_value(v, keys_to_remove) for v in d]
    return {k: remove_all_keys_matching_value(v, keys_to_remove) for k, v in d.items() if k not in keys_to_remove}
```

If I run the function with these keys to remove `keys_to_remove = ('make', 'name')` I'll get the following result:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "age": "100",
        "owned_cars": [{
            "color": "white"
        }, {
            "color": "red"
        }],
        "wished_cars": [{}, {
            "style": "sleek"
        }, {
            "style": "fat"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to adjust this code to be more targeted so it doesn't remove all instances of the key but rather takes into account the root value of the key/path if that makes sense.

So for example if I were to pass in a tuple containing `(('owned_cars', 'make'), 'name')` it would return:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "age": "100",
        "owned_cars": [{
            "color": "white"
        }, {
            "color": "red"
        }],
        "wished_cars": [{
            "make": "honda"
        }, {
            "make": "toyota",
            "style": "sleek"
        }, {
            "style": "fat"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I know I need to keep track of the root key somehow but am unsure how to fold this in. I would appreciate any help in solving this. I always struggle when the recursion gets this complex and would love to see how someone more experienced would approach it so I can improve.

While I am interested in the solution to this problem, I'm more interested in learning how to approach a problem like this?  I understand whats happening at a high level in the recursive method but struggle when I need to start stepping through it. I don't know how to make the leap to adjusting the code to identify the root path.

Comment: "How do you approach difficult recursion problems as a developer?" Can you rename this please to something specific? The question title looks like the usual rubbish that's on the main page but it looks like you have a specific question. You risk getting downvoted from the title alone

Comment: It would also be helpful if you run your JSON through jsonlint.com (and pasting its output) before posting, or printing it with indentation

Comment: I just did. Thanks!

Comment: btw I think a better specification of `keys_to_remove` would be: `(('owned_cars', 'make'), 'name')` so that the strings don't have to be split to recover actual key names.

Comment: @cauthon for `("owned_cars", "make")` would it only remove `"make"` if the immediate parent is `"owned_cars"`? Or is it possible that additional levels of data could exist between?

Comment: @Mulan Yes.  My initial thinking would be to have it only target direct paths.  If there was an additional level in between we would need to pass in 3 values to the inner tuple assuming there was only 1 additional data layer in between ... something like (('owned_cars', 'additional_layer', 'make'), 'name').  And now that I'm thinking about it, we may need to use a list to keep the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**division of complexity**

We could start with a `remove` function that takes any `t` and any number of `paths` -

```py
def remove(t, *paths):
  for p in paths:
    t = remove1(t, p)
  return t
```

As you can see, it has a simple operation calling `remove1(t, p)` for all `p` in the provided paths. The final `t` is returned. This separates the complexity of removing a *single* path and removing *many* paths. We offload the majority of the work to `remove1`.

**remove1**

Your original code is pretty close. This `remove1` takes any `t` and a *single* `path`.

1. If the `path` is empty, return `t` unmodified
2. (inductive) the `path` has at least one element. If `t` is a list, apply `remove1(e, path)` for all `e` of the list `t`
3. (inductive) that `path` has at least one element and `t` is not a list. If `t` is a dictionary -

   - If the `path` has only one element, create a new dictionary with `k` assigned to the result of the sub-problem `remove1(v, path)` for all `k,v` of the dictionary `t`, excluding any `k` matching the path's element, `path[0]`
   - (inductive) the `path` has at least two elements. Create a new dictionary with `k` assigned to the result sub-problem `remove1(v, path[1:])` if `k` matches the *first* element of that `path` otherwise assign `k` to the result of the sub-problem `remove1(v, path)` for all `k,v` of the dictionary `t`.
4. (inductive) `t` is a non-list and `t` is a non-dictionary. Return `t` unmodified.

```py
def remove1(t, path):
  if not path:
    return t
  elif isinstance(t, list):
    return list(remove1(e, path) for e in t)
  elif isinstance(t, dict):
    if len(path) == 1:
      return {k:remove1(v, path) for (k,v) in t.items() if not k == path[0] }
    else:
      return {k:remove1(v, path[1:]) if k == path[0] else remove1(v, path) for (k,v) in t.items()}
  else:
    return t
```

**modification to the input data**

I added another layer to your data so we can see precisely how `remove` is working -

```py
data = {
  "results": [{
    "name": "john doe",
    "age": "100",
    "owned_cars": [{
      "additional_layer": {  # <-- additional layer
        "make": "foo",
        "color": "green"
      }
    }, {
      "make": "ford",
      "color": "white"
    }, {
      "make": "bmw",
      "color": "red"
    }],
    "wished_cars": [{
      "make": "honda"
    }, {
      "make": "toyota",
      "style": "sleek"
    }, {
      "style": "fat"
    }]
  }]
}
```

**demo**

Let's see `remove` work now -

```py
import json
data = { ... }
new_data = remove(data, ("owned_cars", "make"), ("style",))
print(json.dumps(new_data, indent=2))
```

This says remove all `"make"` keys that are any descendant of `"owned_cars"` keys and remove all `"style"` keys -

```py
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "age": "100",
      "owned_cars": [
        {
          "additional_layer": {
                                  # <-- make removed
            "color": "green"
          }
        },
        {
                                  # <-- make removed
          "color": "white"
        },
        {
                                  # <-- make removed
          "color": "red"
        }
      ],
      "wished_cars": [
        {
          "make": "honda"      # <-- make not removed
        },
        {
          "make": "toyota"     # <-- make not removed
                               # <-- style removed
        },
        {}                     # <-- style removed
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @cauthon, if you want it to target absolute paths, that would be a different function. This code gets you very close to that answer. Can you think of how you would modify it to get that behavior?

Comment: Thank you! This works great - I will admit I'm a bit jealous at how quickly you were able to break down the problem and solve it. I guess it just comes with time and practice.  Do you have any blog or book recommendations to improve this skill?

Comment: You're very welcome. It definitely takes some practice but you'll catch on sooner than you think. I don't have books on the topic to recommend but I've written [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a633183%20%5brecursion%5d%20%5bpython%5d%20inductive) on python, recursion and inductive reasoning. If you have any follow up questions, don't be shy ^^